# Is it possible to have type paths in which multiple segments have angle-bracket parameters?

Tags: rust

I am playing with [`syn`](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn) to parse Rust code. Looking at the type definitions of the AST nodes, I noticed something and got interested: is it possible to have type's path (e.g. `a::b::c`) where there are multiple segments which have angle-bracket parameters? So far I've only seen angle-bracket parameters on the last segment.

Here are the type definitions of some AST nodes; [`Ty`](https://dtolnay.github.io/syn/syn/enum.Ty.html):

```
pub enum Ty {
    ...
    Path(Option<QSelf>, Path),
}
```

[`Path`](https://dtolnay.github.io/syn/syn/struct.Path.html):

```
pub struct Path {
    pub global: bool,
    pub segments: Vec<PathSegment>,
}
```

And [`PathSegment`](https://dtolnay.github.io/syn/syn/struct.PathSegment.html)

```
pub struct PathSegment {
    pub ident: Ident,
    pub parameters: PathParameters,
}
```

So apparently after parsing a Rust type it is possible to have parameters on each path segment, like `A<i32>::B<i32>` for **type**. Is that really possible? Maybe not with type parameters, but lifetimes? Or is it only possible in the near future after an RFC was merged?

This is question is only in context of type.

Comment: Hi! I've found your original question a bit difficult to understand. I attempted to reformulate a few sentences to make things more clear. I also answered based on my understanding of your original question. If I made a mistake or you just disagree with my changes, just click on "rollback".

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt My question is only about types, if it is not clear, you can reformulte my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible today to have a path with generic parameters on multiple segments. For example, you could write this:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    _dummy: T,
}
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn bar<U>() {}
}

// So many parameters!
Foo::<u32>::bar::<char>();
```

Another example with `Option` from the standard library:

```
Option::<u32>::ok_or::<char>(None, 'a');
```

However, that only works because the last segment is a function. But that's all we can do right now: parameters on *two* segments, one of which is a function. We can have the following possible path segments:

- **Modules/Crates**

  - Can be followed by: module, type, function
  - Can **not** have any generic parameters
- **Types**

  - Can be followed by: type¹, function
  - **Can** have generic parameters
- **Functions**

  - Can be followed by: *nothing*
  - **Can** have generic parameters

Ignoring the (¹) for a moment, one could think that we can just nest a lot of types in one another to create arbitrarily long paths with type parameter on each segment. But (!) a type can only be followed by another type if this other type is an *associated type*. And right now, associated types **cannot** have type parameters. However, this will probably [change soon](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1598).

So in summary: today, paths to a type have at most one segment with angle-bracket parameters. But this is very likely to change in the near future.

Comment: Both of your examples are not types. Or I missed something? Full path of function != type

Comment: @fghj My answer already contained all the information to answer your question. I reformulated it a bit to make it more clear.

Answer (score -1):

It is already possible for each segment to have parameters:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    t: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn bar<U>() {}
}

fn main() {
    Foo::<u8>::bar::<u32>();
}
```

Comment: You example is not `type`

Comment: I read the question as being about paths, not specifically type paths.

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear, I mean paths only in context of types. Not abstract path to module, crates and so on.

Comment: Then Lukas Kalbertodt's answer answers your question: types can follow types with associated types, and while those cannot be generic yet, it will probably change in the future.